# Safari doesn't respect -F when opening with 'open -F -n -a Safari <url>' on the command line

Tags: macos, terminal, safari

Reading the man page for 'open' the -F flag should open an app in fresh mode.
However if I have already an instance of Safari running with 3 windows open and invoke

```
open -F -n -a  Safari <url>
```

Safari opens in a new instance and also opens the URL but before doing that it opens also the 3 windows from the already running instance in the new instance.
Is there a way to avoid that ?
(It appears rather as a bug than as a feature...the -F flag of the open command is completely ignored)

Comment: Does "fresh mode" mean anything to Safari? I'm guessing that Safari is getting its "this is what I need to open" behavior from some data it is syncing from somewhere else, and that is governing how it starts, and fresh mode may simply not impact that.

Comment: @music2myear The man page doesn't tell to which processes the -F flag means something...so I'm just in the dust. I'd like to use the new instance Safari for running isolated tests to avoid disturbing my main work instance..it has of course no value for me if all open windows are duplicated in this new instance.

Comment: It's possible (it seems likely at this point) that open -F is the wrong way to do what you want and that you've got yourself into an X-Y Problem corner. Perhaps take a step backwards and begin looking into how you open a fresh instance of Safari? You mention "isolated tests" leading me to think this has to do with development of some sort. If you rewrite your question here, please make sure to be specific and detailed as to why you are trying to get a fresh Safari window, as that information, it seems to me, will be important to finding the right method.